# Read private key from smart card to digitally sign XML document

Tags: java, digital-signature

I'm developing an application where a user should be able to digitally sign XML documents using a smart card, which would hold their private key.

During testing, I am able to generate the xml signature given the file paths of the two keys (public and private).

My problem is how to read the private key from the smart card.
I am able to get a response from the card using the following code:

```
        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();

        CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

        Card card = terminal.connect("*");
        System.out.println("Card: " + card);

        CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
        ResponseAPDU r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08));

        String hex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(r.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Response: " + hex);
```

Any help would be appreciated on how to read/view card contents in order to locate the private key.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot get the key from the card; that's the whole point of the smart card.